# How to color points in excel XY scatter charts in VBA based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through each point in an xy chart with multiple series and change the color based on a specific if condition (if there is a value in a specific cell).

This is driving me nuts because it is very inconsistent (sometimes just removes borders and fill remains, sometimes just removes fill and borders remain).

Extract is below.
I have tried with:

```
'MarkerBackgroundColor = rgb(255,255,255)
'MarkerForegroundColor = rgb(255,255,255)
```

Also tried making it true then back to false (seems to work for the .line...)
FYI - the `If` condition works, I have tested with msgbox and it is triggering at the correct times (in case you care - it is reading for blank cell values starting row 3 and jumps 4 columns every iteration of i, starting from column 7).

Code is below:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim cht as Chart

set ws = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Chart_Name")

For i = 2 To 8
    For x = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Count
        If ws.Cells(x + 2, i + 5 + (3 * (i - 2))).Value = "" Or ws.Cells(x + 2, i + 5 + (3 * (i - 2))).Value = " " Then
            With cht.SeriesCollection(i).Points(x)
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor = rgb(255, 255, 255)              
                .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

            End With
        Else
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

Comment: Try setting both to a default at the beginning of your code, and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I "fixed" it - `cht.SeriesCollection(i).Points(x).MarkerStyle = -4142` (i.e. marker type = none) did it.

Still not sure why this happened - seems `Format.Fill` is not very reliable.

If someone has an explanation, would still be much appreciated.

Comment: The explanation is that the object model around formatting of chart data is incomplete and a bit wonky. My own code is full of workarounds, and there are some things I can't quite do in VBA which are easy in the Excel interface.